# Using the GPS instead of Google Location Services in Chrome

Tags: gps, geolocation, privacy, chrome-for-android

I do not consent to Google collecting constant background information about my position at all times through their Google Location Service program. So I have got that option disabled.

I can get just about everything to work with just the GPS. Except for the Google Chrome browser. It keeps referring me back to enabling the Google Location Service option. Which does not make sense. The HTML5 GeoLocation API wants latitude and longitude, which the GPS is perfectly capable of providing on it’s own without involving Google’s servers. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Android has two main permission levels for apps, Precise Location and Coarse Location. Precise location uses GPS (along with other sources), Coarse Location generally doesn't use the GPS at all, and just uses the other sources. I suspect that Chrome is attempting to protect your privacy by denying random websites access to the GPS.

Comment: That does not make sense, GAThrawn. Random websites cannot get access to the GPS. The HTML5 Geolocation API requires a per-domain permission prompt before location information is transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox, no location needed, blocks that nosy one
use duckduckgo search also does not track or sell, true privacy